# Return the current user with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am currently developing an API using Django.

**However**, I would like to create a view that returns the current User with the following endpoint: `/users/current/`.

To do so, I created a list view and filtered the queryset on the user that made the request. That works, but the result is a list, not a single object. Combined with pagination, the result looks way too complicated and inconsistent compared to other endpoints.

I also tried to create a detail view and filtering the queryset, but DRF complains that I provided no pk or slug.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

With something like this you're probably best off breaking out of the generic views and writing the view yourself.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

You could also do the same thing using a class based view like so...

```
class CurrentUserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Of course, there's also no requirement that you use a serializer, you could equally well just pull out the fields you need from the user instance.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user(request):
    user = request.user
    return Response({
        'username': user.username,
        'email': user.email,
        ...
    })
```

Comment: Note: I had to use `serializer = UserSerializer(request.user, context={'request': request})` because my user serializer includes a hyperlink `url` field (based on the default project).

Answer (score 38):

The best way is to use the power of `viewsets.ModelViewSet` like so:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')

        if pk == "current":
            return self.request.user

        return super().get_object()
```

`viewsets.ModelViewSet` is a combination of `mixins.CreateModelMixin` + `mixins.RetrieveModelMixin` + `mixins.UpdateModelMixin` + `mixins.DestroyModelMixin` + `mixins.ListModelMixin` + `viewsets.GenericViewSet`. If you need just list all or get particular user including currently authenticated you need just replace it like this

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 13):

If you must use the generic view set for some reason, you could do something like this,

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`retrieve` method is called when the client requests a single instance using an identifier like a primary key `/users/10` would trigger the retrieve method normally. Retrieve itself calls `get_object`. If you want the view to always return the current used then you could modify `get_object` and force `list` method to return a single item instead of a list by calling and returning `self.retrieve` inside it.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using full power of `ModelViewSet` you can use mixins. There is `RetrieveModelMixin` used to retrieve single object just like it is mentioned here - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example_3

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

If you need also update your model, just add `UpdateModelMixin`.

Comment: What would be the function to override to partial update the User using the same view class?

Answer (score 9):

I used a `ModelViewSet` like this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('pk') == 'current' and request.user:
            kwargs['pk'] = request.user.pk

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: elb, i tried to use the above function but it seems like dispatch() runs too early that request.user is still anonymous, user is assigned after the dispatch is ran.. any alternative for that?

Comment: This one works fine for me. You may want to change `request.user` to `request.user.is_authenticated()`. Cuz `request.user` is `AnonymousUser` if you are not logged in.

Comment: Works with SessionAuthentication. Doesn't work when using TokenAuthentication. request.user is anonymous inside dispatch.

Comment: This will not work with Token authentication. Where authentication is performed is inside of initial() call, and that is done in dispatch, so use will never be authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

Use this way to get logged in user data in django rest framework

```
class LoggedInUserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Add the api in urls.py file.

```
path('logged_in_user', LoggedInUserView.as_view())
```

Comment: `UserSerializer(request.user)` can be used instead )