# Django Rest how to save current user when creating an new blog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

When I am creating an blog post I also want to automatically save the current user without selecting the user manually as a blog author.

here is my code:

**models.py**:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
```

**views.py**

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    pagination_class = BlogPagination
    lookup_field = 'blog_slug'

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
        elif self.action == 'list':
            permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

        else:
            permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly & IsAuthorGroup]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return the current user with Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770488/return-the-current-user-with-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your serializer like below. It picks up the user from the request context and creates the blog.

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ["author"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        blog = Blog.objects.create(**validated_data, author=user)

        return blog
```